# Installing NetXtreme II 10 Gigabit Driver on Windows 7

Tags: drivers

I have a Windows 7 Dell with a Broadcom 57810 10G Ethernet card. I have installed the Windows Server 2008 R2 [associated drivers](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtremeii10.php), but in the device manager the "Ethernet Controller" on the relevant PCIe slot has not installed driver.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this Ethernet card driver issue?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: @ChrisS: Yes I have.

Comment: Failing that, right click the "Ethernet Controller" in Device Manager, select Update Driver, Browse, find the drivers you downloaded, and follow the rest of the wizard.

Comment: @ChrisS: I tried that but the driver installer comes in a "setup" executable, so that specific driver files cannot be found for manual installation.

Comment: @randomblue, does the setup .exe attempt to extract to a folder anywhere?

Comment: Extract the .exe from the command line: `setup.exe /t:C:<target_dir> /c` or use 7Zip (or similar program like WinRAR) to extract it.

Comment: Have you tried to let Windows Update find the correct driver as an alternative?

Comment: @Cole: The `target_dir` doesn't get populated.